# Qual è il significato di "tarare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Non era una storia tanto semplice, due amici che si scambiano un po' la vita e vediamo come butta. Era una storia che aveva anche delle implicazioni filosofiche, per Jeremy. Ad esempio: se tu devi passare la tua vita a un altro raccontandogliela, la devi vivere normalmente come ti viene o la devi già vivere diversa, *tarandola* su di lui? Ma se è cosí, vuol dire che non vivi piú la tua, di vita, ma quella che farebbe l'altro. Quindi tu non sei piú tu, sei diventato l'altro?

Ho cercato il significato di "tarare" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire il suo significato in questo contesto. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La tara è la differenza tra il peso lordo e il peso netto di un oggetto.

Tarare una bilancia significa impostare una bilancia in modo tale che escluda il peso dello tara e che il peso mostrato sia il peso netto dell'oggetto.

Per analogia / metafora si può usare "tarare" per descrivere in generale un'operazione che "imposta qualcosa in funzione di qualcos'altro".

Quindi in "se tu devi passare la tua vita a un altro raccontandogliela, la devi vivere normalmente come ti viene o la devi già vivere diversa, tarandola su di lui?" viene descritto un indugiare tra il prediligere il "vivere la vita normalmente come viene" e il ""vivere la vita in modo diverso *impostandola in funzione dell'altro*".

---

Dato che tarare una bilancia è un operazione che "sottrae" al peso lordo di un oggetto, spesso si usa "tarato" / "tarata" anche per descrivere una una persona con una qualche sorta di deficienza mentale, ed è piuttosto offensivo, quindi dovrebbe essere usato con attenzione.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao Charo,

In questo contesto, la domanda che Jeremy si pone è, data la descrizione della vita dell'altro che gli viene data, deve quindi:

- Usare tale descrizione come un punto di partenza e, da lì in poi, usare il proprio giudizio nel prendere decisioni e decidere come condurre il resto della vita o;
- Ad ogni "bivio", cercare di immagine come l'altro avrebbe reagito e, anche se questo andrebbe contro l'istinto o le preferenze di Jeremy, agire comunque in base a ciò.

Ovvero, "tarare" in questo caso assume la funzione di sinonimo di "calibrare" o "pre-impostare", cioè giungere a conclusioni dal punto di vista dell'altro invece che dal proprio.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @MrD, e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Scusa, perché "pre-impostare" invece di "impostare"? C'è qualche differenza?

Answer (score 0):

Tarare significa anche "adattare". Volendo parlare della mia vita a qualcuno, posso tarare il racconto a seconda degli interessi, dei gusti e delle capacità dell'ascoltatore.
(Uno dei sinonimi di "Tarare" è "aggiustare", che a sua volta è sinonimo di "adattare" - isinonimi.it)

Answer (score 0):

La *taratura* di uno strumento è l'operazione che permette di correggerne la lettura per fare in modo che il valore mostrato sia quello corretto (ossia quello mostrato da qualunque altro strumento).

Analogamente in questo contesto per *tarare la vita* si intende modificare i propri comportamenti per fare in modo che dall'esterno risultino indistinguibili da quelli dell'altro.

Answer (score 0):

Direi che la potresti intendere come "devi già vivere diversa, *basandola* su di lui". 
Basando, calibrando, impostando... la vita di una persona su quella di un'altra persona significherebbe, ad un estremo, il lasciare la propria personalità finendo con l'imitare l'altro ("Quindi tu non sei più tu, sei diventato l'altro?").

Vivere *in funzione* di un'altra persona per me significa (spignolando sul concetto) più il sacrificare aspetti della propria vita per quella persona facendone il centro della propria esistenza, ma non l'immedesimarsi in quella persona che, invece, sembra sia il dubbio del personaggio del libro. Per esempio una madre può vivere in funzione di un figlio.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Erik, e grazie della risposta!